# Can we add a current limiter circuit to LM2576 fixed voltage version?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, current-limiting, switching-regulator

I know I can add an external current sense and comparator circuit to the feedback pin of [LM2576-ADJ](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf?ts=1641091695893&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) version to limit current, but can we make such a modified arrangement to a fixed version of the switcher?

Answer (score 1):

> *I know I can add an external current sense and comparator circuit to
> the Feed back pin of LM2576-ADJ version to limit current.*

In the fixed voltage versions of the LM2576, the FB pin is still used except there is an internal resistor divider as per the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf?ts=1641091695893&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). I've taken the liberty of highlighting the value of R2 for the 4 different fixed voltage regulators listed in the data sheet: -: -

[image]

> *But can we make such a modified arrangement to a Fixed version of the
> Switcher?*

Given the schematic from the data sheet shown above I'm pretty certain you can use a very similar modification to obtain current limiting. On an over-current situation, you need to lift the voltage on the FB pin a little above the regulated limit. In order to do this effectively, you need to ensure that you don't also lift the output voltage. So, it's a little more complex than when dealing with the FB pin and external voltage divider of an adjustable regulator but, it's do-able.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBPX4J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: ".. you need to ensure that you don't also lift the output voltage".

Since the output and FB pins are tied together I think we need some sort of a OP-Amp arrangement in between so that the high current info from another op-amp stage should cause this op-amp output to lift the FB pin.
Can you give some more info on how to do that?
Thank you

Comment: @UB_Roy a buffer stage is likely needed. Probably using an op-amp and a diode with feedback from after diode to -Vin. Then, it's easy to lift the voltage because the op-amp output becomes disconnected by the reverse diode. I've added an idea to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the circuit. That node can be pulled up by the output from the differential amplifier which monitors the current? 
Something like this adjustable version? https://www.smbaker.com/lm2576-constant-voltage-constant-current-switching-power-supply

Comment: I think we are getting into details here that are beyond this question - you should probably ask a new question based on info I have provided in this question and answer session. You also ought to try and properly simulate the circuit you propose.

Comment: Thanks. I tried simulating the LM2576_ADJ version and got it OK. But for the fixed voltage version I am still looking for a LTspice model. Anyway that I will bring in another question.

Comment: Just add R1 and R2 externally to the ADJ version to mimic the fixed version